# Set environment variables Delve

Tags: go, delve

I am attempting to debug my Go program using Delve.

[Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve)

I can debug my unit tests fine, however, I would like to run my whole binary in debug mode and then stop at certain breakpoints.

To run my binary normally I use the command

```
AWS_ENV=development AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 ./${REPONAME}
```

I am trying to run the delve debugger with

```
dlv debug --AWS_ENV=development --AWS_REGION=eu-west-1  main.go
```

However I get the error:

> Error: unknown flag: --AWS_REGION

I assume I am setting the environment variables incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just follow the same format as you did before to set the environment, so that would look like:

`AWS_ENV=development AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 dlv debug main.go`

If you wanted to pass some args to the debugger then it would look like this:

`dlv debug main.go -- --AWS_ENV=development --AWS_REGION=eu-west-1`